# Posting on a friends wall without showing full name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-wall

While I am logged into my Facebook account I would like to send an invite or post to one of my friends wall BUT without letting them know who I am. (maybe not showing the full name)

Its for some kind of quiz where my friend has to guess which of his friends I am.

Is this even possible to implement this via the API similar to that-

```
Facebook.api("me/feed",  onShared, data, "POST");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Issuing a request to me/feed will add a post to the current logged in user, and that user is obviously aware of his own name..

You can of course send the request to USER_ID/feed and then it will post on that user wall, but the user will be aware of the person who posted it on his wall (the one that is logged in to your application).

Facebook don't let you hide that part, and my guess is that they won't in the future, this kind of behavior, even if not meant to harm by you, can cause to a lot of spamming and general misuse of the graph api.

If you still want to have that kind of quiz, you'll have to post things to your own application, then notify the user (using the social channels (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) that someone posted on his "app wall", in your application you can do what ever you want, and so you can not show him who this friend was and then he needs to guess.

Comment: Thanks, but i guess the user has to "like" the app to get notifications?

Comment: Depends on the channel you go with. You can try the Requests: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/ which let you invite a user which did not authorize your application.